# dprp paypal confusion - displaying live

Tags: paypal

I have read through the forums on here and see that the 'DPRP is disabled' message is due to not paying the additional fee for recurring payments.

I did not set the account up so Im not sure exactly what was paid for, I do know that we are using website payments pro.

My confusion comes from the top of the page where is says Recurring Payments are live, is this separate from the direct payment recurring? Does this mean that the account does have dprp or is this displaying live just a generic thing that all accounts have?

We currently do take recurring payments from a hosted paypal page so im wondering whether that is why it is set to live?

We plan to have our own page to take payments rather than a hosted page so any advice would be great.

Thanks in advance

CHeers

Nadeem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error of you don not have DPRP enabled, is just that.  It means that you do not have recurring payments enabled on the account.  You may just have DP (Direct Payments) enabled on your account and not DPRP (Direct Payment Recurring Payments), meaning you would only be able to process single payment transactions not recurring payments.  If you can provide the email adddress to test account I can take a look at it and see what you have enabled on it and can enable it if its not enabled.